# Could not load file or assembly - not working on asp, works on desktop

Tags: c#, c++, asp.net, .net, dependencies

While using a **native dll** dependency on a asp.net **web project** and debugging in VS2015 with **IIS express** I'm getting the dreaded:

> Could not load file or assembly 'XXX.DLL' or one of its dependencies. The specified module could not be found.
>
> **Description**: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> **Exception Details**: System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not load file or assembly 'XXX.DLL' or one of its dependencies. The specified module could not be found.

**HOWEVER** the same dependency works fine in a simple forms app on the same machine - hence I assume all the dependencies and co-dependencies are present

maybe you have some clues, how can this be?

***What I already tried:***

- putting all the potential dependencies in the web project output folder
- putting all the potential dependencies in the /system32/ path
- putting all the potential dependencies in the /system32/inetsrv and /sysWOW64/inetsrv
- installing c++ redistributables (2010, 2012, 2013)
- I 'unblocked' the dlls as they "came from another computer" (CASpol)
- dependency walker did not give any clear results
- process monitor did not give any clear results

**some details:**

VS2015 Community, running on an Azure VM with Windows Server 2012 (test system), clean install

the app uses CGAL and BOOST libraries (c++).

'Dependency tree' is as follows: C# wrapper references a CLR C++ project which in turn references the native C++ (only this one uses CGAL/Boost);

The C# wrapper is then used in the forms app (works) or the asp.net web app (doesn't work);

Putting Cgal dlls (around 6 files) into the bin output folder was enough to run the forms app.

**PS**: of course on my 2 dev machines (Win 7, <strike>Win 10</strike>) the asp.net project works swimmingly - but these contain dedicated installs of the huge c++ references.

**PPS**: I currently really prefer to use iis express due to external reasons. I have to simulate deploying the app on a clean-ish Win10 laptop, in a dev environment, with minimal external installations

**PPPS** it seems the win10 dev machine isn't working after all - **edit: this was the key clue, see my answer below and [Ho do I reference native files in IIS express?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24246547/ho-do-i-reference-native-files-in-iis-express)**

I'm a bit stuck right now, thanks.

Comment: 2 ideas: (1) Can you attack a debugger to the web server process before the fault occurs and possibly get more information.  (2) Strip it back to stub implementation(s) and add code back until it breaks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solution: on Win 10 I copied the dll output (**\bin folder**) into the **Program Files (x86)\IIS Express** folder (as I am using the 32-bit version).

Apparently, this wasn't needed on Win7 - I will have to investigate why

I found this solution in:
[Ho do I reference native files in IIS express?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24246547/ho-do-i-reference-native-files-in-iis-express)

EDIT: **another, more elegant (?) solution** is to disable shadow-copying in web.config as in http://faithlife.codes/blog/2013/05/using-native-dlls-from-asp-net-apps/

"The simplest solution I’ve found is to turn off shadow copying, which causes the DLLs to be loaded directly from the bin directory.(...) Just add a *hostingEnvironment* element to your web.config:"

```
<configuration>
 ...
  <system.web>
    ...
    <hostingEnvironment shadowCopyBinAssemblies="false" />
```

Comment: Disabling the shadow copying worked perfectly for me! I spent way too much time tracing through things until I found this, as debugging didn't reveal the issue, nor did procmon. You should mark it as the answer. :-)